# Avoiding "Setting Locale Failed" Message While Calling Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, message, stderr

Whenever I run my code:

```
$perl my_any_code.pl
```

It always gives me this:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UTF-8` is not a locale name.  Set the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable to a locale that's recognized by your system.  It should probably look like `en_US.UTF-8`.  You can get a list of valid locales by running the command `locale -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Compile list of your locale definitions and reconfigure it.

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Mac M1 Monterey, my quick way to disable that message: Open Terminal -> Preferences -> Advanced tab -> uncheck to Set locale environment variables on startup